# Optimizing for SELECT INTO OUTFILE

Tags: mysql, sql, into-outfile

I have a `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` query that can return up to ~160,000 rows or a few dozen megabytes of data. It takes a long time to run - like 20 minutes. If I do `LIMIT 100` the query takes a fraction of a second, so it seems like my query is probably optimized nearly as well as it can be.

Are there any performance-improving techniques specific to `SELECT INTO OUTFILE`? For example, maybe there's some memory setting in `my.cnf` that helps or something.

Note: this question is not about query optimization so please don't ask to see my query if that's what you're after. There's plenty of help on that available elsewhere. I'm asking for performance techniques that specifically improve `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` queries.

I'm on Ubuntu, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Is this across a network? How long does it take to copy the result file across the same topology?

Measuring with "LIMIT 100" isn't necessarily a very good test for anything.

Generally the difference between SELECT and SELECT INTO OUTFILE is going to be the time it takes to get the data onto a disk somewhere. And that can involve lots of things you aren't telling us much about.